# Parent and Child report in RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I want to create a report (.RDLC) in Visual Studio 2010. The report should show parent record initially when the user clicks the expand button it should load the child records in the same report.

I have employee records which has to be shown as parent record and when the user expands then the detail report should be shown with the list of projects the employee has worked on.

I tried with sub reports, but it showed me the parent records initially and when I select any record then it shows the details records in another report. but I want both Parent and Child records should be shown in same report. There is no grouping between the Parent and Child records. Employee id is the matching column.

Thanks,
Prakash.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to group anything in an RDLC Report is by using the `List` component. Which you can nest as many times as you want. You can even fetch the data from multiple tables, as long as you group on a column which both data-sources have in common (FK).

Adding functionality like collapsing and expanding views comes after you grouped everything nicely.

You could start the list by grouping on employees and adding textboxes with the the data you wish to display. Inside the same rectangle you could then add a new list and group it on  projects, inside this second rectangle you can then add a table, matrix or even add another list to group on something else.

You can find a good tutorial [here](http://gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html). Option 2 is recommended, which is what I tried to describe in words and option 1 is probably what you initially tried, using subreports.